# Error when adding documents to firestore using add() method

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm trying to add documents to firestore using `add()` method. As per the documentation `add()` method generates a unique ID for each document and stores it in any random order and to store it in an ordered manner we need to a `timestamp` field in document. Here's how I'm doing it:

```
def add_data(message):
  message.update({u'timestamp': firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP})
  coll_ref.add(message)
```

When I'm executing the above method I'm getting an error:

`TypeError: ('Cannot convert to a Firestore Value', <object object at 0x104fdebe0>, 'Invalid type', <class 'object'>)`

Why am I getting this error? Is there a bug in `firestore` Python SDK, if so then any patch has been released for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me with the latest version of the Python Admin SDK (verified in the REPL).

```
>>> import firebase_admin
>>> from firebase_admin import firestore
>>> firebase_admin.initialize_app()
<firebase_admin.App object at 0x1080c33d0>
>>> client = firestore.client()
>>> msg = {'timestamp': firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP}
>>> foo = client.collection('foo')
>>> foo.add(msg)
(seconds: 1569404958
nanos: 428866000
, <google.cloud.firestore_v1.document.DocumentReference object at 0x108dfc610>)
```

This uses v1.4.0 of `google-cloud-firestore` underneath. Check your library versions, imports etc.

Comment: I'm using v0.31.0 of `google-cloud-firestore`. I was right then it is because of improper version. Is there any work around for this if I plan on sticking with v0.31.0?

Comment: Unlikely. What is preventing you from upgrading?

Comment: Managerial constraints.